# ionic how to call a function in dynamic html from a database

Tags: html, ionic-framework, onclick, anchor, ionic4

I have a text message that my ionic app retrieves from an api that has an anchor link which needs to redirect to another page when tapped.

The html from the api is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToOtherPage()">Tap Here</a>
```

The ionic function is:

```
goToOtherPage(): void {
  this.navCtrl.push(OtherPage);
}
```

I have tried:

```
<a onclick="goToOtherPage()">Tap Here</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#" (click)="goToOtherPage()">Tap Here</a>
```

but the first two give the message:

goToOtherPage is not defined

and the last one does nothing.

Does anyone know how I can trigger a function from dynamically retrieved html?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work due to the DomSantizer that sanitizes unsafe html. I recommend retrieving the different parts of the message (eg. using JSON) and generating the page link and message via your page/component.

Comment: I already have functionality to handle this using Angular's bypassSecurityTrustHtml function. I just need the final piece of the puzzle to be able trigger the goToOtherPage function from an anchor link.